# Given $ \mid x - y \mid = 1$ and equality predicates in $ \mathbb{C} $.How to get $ \mid x - y \mid = \frac{1}{2} $?

Tags: logic, complex-numbers

You are given $ \mid x - y \mid = 1$ and equality predicates in $ \mathbb{C} $ .
Your task is to construct the predicate $ \mid x - y \mid = \frac{1}{2} $.

Can you help me with this task?

For exmaple, I can do it if there was $ 2 $ instead of $ \frac {1}{2} $

$ \exists z (\mid x - z \mid = 1) \land(\mid y - z \mid = 1) \land (\forall a ((\mid x - a \mid = 1) \land (\mid y - a \mid = 1)) \to (z = a)$)

Similarly we can do that for any $ k \in \mathbb{N} $. I can get $ k\times\sqrt{3}$ too. I just cannot get any less distances than $ 1 $.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks!

I'm new to this field so I have't tried much. I can construct $ \mid x - y \mid = k $ for k in N, $ \mid x - y \mid = k\sqrt{3} $ for k in N (basiclaly anything we can get times $ k $ :D), but I cannot get a less distance than `1`.

Comment: Can you add  those constructions to your Post?  It is always good to see hpw far you got; it'll help us see where your thinking is at, if there are any mistakes you made, give hints how to proceed, or enable us to see the next steps.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I'll edit soon.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Thanks for the advice! @Shaun

Comment: IMO the formula for $2$ is wrong; we may have that the two "segments" $xz$ and $zy$ are perpendicular in the complex plane, and this means that the distance $|x-y|$ is not $2$

Comment: That's why I said that there is exacly one such point (for any point like that it's the same as z).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this can be obtained from the geometric construction of bisecting a line segment using compasses only (no straightedge).  You can find such a construction [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/compass14.shtml).

Comment: Sorry for the previous reply, thank you very much !!